# "Term reference" for two language versions

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I'm currently working on a Drupal's website for my client. We have a small issue related to new fields in "content types".

I've created a new field with field type "Term reference". We're using terms for isotpe grid, and it should work in both language versions - NL and EN.

That field only displays a single language version (default one), even when we change thhe language.

Here is an example - "field_thema[nl][8]", it supposed to be:

```
"field_thema[nl][8]"
```

and

```
"field_thema[en][8]"
```

Is there any way we could fix this?

Comment: Is your issue at the form level where you are adding the reference or on the output level?

Comment: Well, it's related to both, form and output. In the input form there is an issue with saving it in EN version as I mentioned in the question. On the other hand, output don't display any classes that are auto generated from the terms.

Answer (score 0):

is this a Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 question ?

in Drupal 7 you can use i18n_taxonomy submodule of i18n module.

Comment: We are using Drupal 7 with i18n_taxonomy module enabled :(